# iOS: Adding child view controller does not show child's components

Tags: ios, swift

There are two view controllers, `MainViewController` and `ChildViewController`, I want to add `ChildViewController` to `MainViewController` and this is my code:

**MainViewController.swift**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.add(ChildViewController(), in: containerView)
    }

}
```

**ChildViewController.swift**

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("ChildViewController is loaded")
    }

}
```

**UIViewController+Ext.swift**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func add(_ child: UIViewController, in container: UIView) {
        addChild(child)
        container.addSubview(child.view)
        child.view.frame = container.bounds
        child.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    func add(_ child: UIViewController) {
        add(child, in: view)
    }
    
    func remove(from view: UIView) {
        guard parent != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        willMove(toParent: nil)
        removeFromParent()
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
    func remove() {
        remove(from: view)
    }
}
```

**Storyboard**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

"`ChildViewController is loaded`" appears in the terminal but the UI components are not loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.add(ChildViewController(), in: containerView)
```

You are creating a `ChildViewController` instance programatically instead of getting it from the storyboard.

```
if let childViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildViewController") {
    self.add(ChildViewController(), in: containerView)
}
```